# Spring Data JPA @Query with foreign key: Parameter not matched

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a table "Signal" with id, volume and object_id columns.

Object_id is a foreign key. I need to retrieve each signal that has a particular object_id.

Im trying to use this Query

```
public interface SignalRepository extends JpaRepository<Signal, Integer> {
    @Query("select s from Signal s where s.object = ?1")
    Optional<List<Signal>> findSignalByObjectId(Integer objectId);

}
```

It doens't work. If I change `"?1"` to `1` it gets the hardcoded value. If I try to query the "volume", it works fine.

I get this error:

> Blockquote
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring data to generate the underlying query like this :

```
public interface SignalRepository extends JpaRepository<Signal, Integer> {
    List<Signal> findSignalByObjectId(Integer objectId);
}
```

or you can write the query with this return type and parameter:

```
public interface SignalRepository extends JpaRepository<Signal, Integer> {
    @Query("select s from Signal s where s.object = :id")
    List<Signal> findSignalByObjectId(@Param("id") Integer objectId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you omit the query and let spring data generate one for you. So your case may be represented somehow like that (in case of proper relation mapping defined):

```
public interface SignalRepository extends JpaRepository<Signal, Integer> {
    Optional<Signal> findByObject(YourObjectType object);
}
```

If you provide more info e.g. your entities - you can get more help.